# Can we extract the second result set of stored procedure using SQL query in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have a stored procedure that returns 2 result sets and the question here is can we directly fetch any specific result set using SQL query? For eg: I just want to get the second result set only so can I do this? And I just want to do this only in MySQL workbench.

Like: We can call the stored procedure directly using **call** command and if we have output variables in the stored procedure then we can directly extract the output variables using the **select** command. Similarly can we extract the second result set only?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please be more detailed. For example, add simplified procedure code. *I just want to get the second result set only so can I do this?* Comment SELECT which produces 1st recordset (you may add IN parameter which defines does this 1st SELECT will be executed or not).

Comment: Hi @Akina, when I call my stored procedure using `call` command like: **call storedProcedureName("input1, input2")** so it returns two result sets in workbench, but in my scenario, I just want to deal with the second result set.

Comment: *in my scenario, I just want to deal with the second result set.* My above comment matches this need. *I call my stored procedure using call command like: `call storedProcedureName("input1, input2")`* - Does SP has one parameter, and you provide shown CSV literal into it? And why you use dquotes for string literal quoting?

Comment: I'm sorry, the correct call is **call storedProcedureName('input1', 'input2')**, I don't have internal details of the stored procedure, I just want to extract the second result set using SQL query. So do you have any idea about it?

Comment: In workbench - simply select needed tab in the bottom of Result Grid. See [MySQL Workbench Manual  /  ...  /  Result Grid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-sql-editor-results.html): *If the script contains multiple statements, a result subtab will be generated for each statemented that returned results.*

Comment: Yes, I'm getting two subtabs for this, but is it possible to get only one result set(subtab) using any query?

Comment: No. If a resultset is returned then Workbench will show it. But you may simply close the tabs which you do not need in.